# Is this possible to activate app in terminate state if user enter into any region - iOS

Tags: ios, geofencing, relaunch

- I have implemented geofencing functionality in my App.
- I get notified when user enter into particular region with below method

> ```
> func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
>     if region is CLCircularRegion {
>       handleEvent(forRegion: region)
>     }
>   }
> ```

Above method is calling even in terminated state.

- Is there any way to relaunch or activate application in terminated
  state if enter into the region.

Comment: why you wanna do that ? Any functionality you want to achieve after entering any region ?

Comment: As in open the app up into the foreground without the user actually opening it? No, you can't. You can immediately fire a local notification, and if the user presses it'll open up

Comment: @Dev_Tandel Yes I want to place my order after entering any particular region. Please let me know if you have any resolution to do this.

Comment: @DatForis I want to call API to place my order without location notification. Is there any way?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to actually open up an app from the terminated state without the user actually having anything to do with it is to use CLRegion monitoring. So sadly not. If the app were to be in the background you can send a remote notification with the `content-available` key set to 1, and that would actually allow you to run code in the background to do some network call, or whatever, but for a limited time of course